# Blender cycles halo material on particles - how to texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]I can produce halo materials in cycles using the point density texture node. What I get are little fluffy glowing balls. In BI I can apply textures to the halo that will make them less fluffy. How do I do that in cycles? I've tried inserting a spherical gradient node between point density fac and emission strength slots but just get a complete white-out in the domain.

edit: screenshots. I'd like to be able to experiment with the look of the halos. From memory (I'd have to dust off ancient files) there was a way to "harden" the edges of each halo. There were other effects like star rays and rings too. I think you could add textures. Below is the result of me playing with nodes. It's closer to the look I'm after but I've no idea why or how this configuration produces that result. It's not exactly what I'm after. For example, the point density color setting is set to "Age", which I had originally flipped using the color ramp because I wanted the halos to be brightest at birth instead of death. With my blind experimental node set up flipping the color ramp causes the white out I mentioned. So I'm after guidance on how to alter the look of halos in cycles. A pointer to some reference is fine. I haven't come across anything apart from basics though.[image: Blind experiment!]

Comment: can you show images of your current nodes and results and an example of what you are after?